Dartfrog websocket broadcast message
i was digging inside of dart_frog to know it capabilities , it sounds awesome until i've started using websocket ,
i've implemented it like this way
  final handler = webSocketHandler(
    (channel, protocol) {
      final getIt = GetIt.instance;

      getIt<TripSocket>().init(channel);
      // A new client has connected to our server.
      print('connected');

      // Send a message to the client.
      channel.sink.add('hello from the server');

      // Listen for messages from the client.
      channel.stream.listen(
        print,
        // The client has disconnected.
        onDone: () => print('disconnected'),
      );
    },
  );

here i was registering the channel to use it else where not just in this endpoint,
my use case when a new POST request arrives to create trip endpoint it just emit a message to the all  web-socket clients, but it only use that channel and only send a event to the last connected client
usage was
    final channel = getIt<TripSocket>().channel;
    print(channel?.protocol);
    if (channel != null) {
      await channel.ready.then(
        (_) {
          channel.sink.add(
            jsonEncode(
              {
                'event': 'new-trip',
                'trip': trip?.toJson(),
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ).onError((e, st) async {
        print('socket error: $e ');
      });
    }

i know that there is emit in other frameworks that broadcasts event to all clients who listen to that channel . how to do this using dart_frog package?
